# How to access texture/models from cloud/WEB at run time in android app using Unity 3D?

Tags: android, azure, unity-game-engine, azure-blob-storage

I have been trying to download and load the texture or other models from a WEB at run time by using WWW class.
The app works well on Unity Editor but when I deploy it on android device it doesn't load/download the texture.
Please somebody guide me.
I have used the following code in script.

```
void Start()
{
StartCoroutine(loadMovie());
}
IEnumerator loadTexture()
{
WWW www = new WWW("http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg");
yield return www;
// Debug.Log(www.movie.duration + " <--- wwww");
if (www.error != null)
{
Debug.Log("Error: Can't load texture! - " + www.error);
yield break;
}
else
{
Texture2D texture = www.texture as Texture2D;
Debug.Log("Texture loaded");
Debug.Log(www.texture);
gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;
}
}
```

Comment: so which error do you get ?

Comment: I am getting no error. When I just deploy this app on android device, it doesn't download/load the texture from the WEB/Cloud. Though it works fine at Unity Editor.

Comment: Try to print logs on GUI somewhere at screen so you can exactly see what's happening when on device. you can see logs directly on system if you have eclipse or android studio. quick one would be printing logs on mobile screen.

Comment: @AffanShahab Hi, I tried this too. It shows no error but the values of progress (www.progress I used in while loop after modifying the code s given below) are different while running app on unity editor and android device. But the same problem occurs that I doesn't show the texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, remove Debug.Log(www.texture); from the code, then re-try your code.

You have `IEnumerator loadTexture()` but you are calling `StartCoroutine(loadMovie());` . This means that you are likely calling another function or maybe that's a type in your question.

```
void Start()
{
StartCoroutine(loadTexture());
}

IEnumerator loadTexture()
{
WWW www = new WWW("http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg");

//Wait for download to finish
while(!www.isDone){
Debug.Log("Progress: "+www.progress);
yield return null;
}

if ((www==null) || (www.error != null))
{
Debug.Log("Error: Can't load texture! - " + www.error);
yield break;
}

gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = www.texture;
}
```

Not compiled but should work.

**EDIT**:
From the file you sent, change the Minimum API Level to 4.1.

Comment: Yes. I had found the error and corrected it (loadTexture) in start method.
But still this doesn't work.

Comment: Try the code I posted above. Just copy it and replace it with your current code.

Comment: I also tried your code. But still I am facing the same problem. Though I have given the internet permissions in Android Manifest but the texture is not being loaded in Android.

Comment: Can you try another image link and see what happens?

Comment: Yes I have tried that too but the same problem occurs.

Comment: I got my android device with me here and if yous still need help, remove important textures or files from your project then zip and upload the link here. I think the problem is from the scene or from another script. I will try to find out what it is.

Comment: There is nothing big in this project. I have just this and on scene I have just taken a plane which shows the texture. That's it.

Comment: Well If you want then here is the complete Demo Project of my app:https://www.dropbox.com/s/jnc8fpmbaxn674h/DemoProject.rar?dl=0

Comment: looking at it. will let youknow  if i find anything wrong

Comment: I just ran the code and it works. It works on my android. I wasn't able to run this on my android until I changed the **Minimum API Level** to **4.1**. It was on **Android 5.0 Lollipop**. If that did not work then open your browser from your android device and go to http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg. If you can't see the image then the problem is your phone.

Comment: Yes. Dear the problem was API Level. Actually I have Android Lolipop installed on my device but selecting API Level 4.1 solved my problem.
Thanks allot.

Comment: You can accept the answer if that helped you. I modified the original answer to include the "change the Minimum API Level to 4.1" in my comment. I guess that was a bug.