# UnityWebRequest and/or HttpWebRequest give 403 on Android with PUT

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, network-programming, put

*(( Ive also posted this on Unity Answers and on GameDev but x-posting here in case any C# networking heads can point out any obvious errors in my HttpWebRequest code... ))*

I am trying to post an image captured through my game to Facebook through their SDK, and as it requires a URI, I wrote a simple AWS Lambda function to take a byte array and upload it to an AWS bucket. The AWS function takes a call and then returns a URL to call PUT to with the image data... 
So the idea is, if the response is 200, use that URL to post to FB.

But - using Unity 5.2.x to 5.3.4, and Android 4.4 - 6.1 - it *always gives me a 403 response*, while working fine on iOS.

So, I have a method that takes a byte[] then does this:

```
    WWW w = new WWW("https://my-amazon-function-to-call");
    yield return w;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(w.error)) {
        Debug.LogError(w.error);
    }
    else 
    {
             var dict = Json.Deserialize(w.text) as Dictionary<string,object>;
             string oneTimeUploadUrl = (string)dict["oneTimeUploadUrl"]; // Private URL
             string resultUrl = (string)dict["resultUrl"]; // Public URL

            UnityWebRequest aws = UnityWebRequest.Put(oneTimeUploadUrl, bytes);
            yield return aws.Send();
            if(aws.isError) 
            {
                Debug.LogError("AWS ERROR: " + aws.error);
            }
            if(aws.responseCode == 200)
            {
                FeedShare(new Uri(resultUrl), _cachedMessage);    // FB call
            }
    }
```

Pretty simple, right? 
On iOS, yes it is. But Android it continually gives me a 403 response on the PUT operation.

So, I've taken to wrapping this in an iOS-specific #ifdef and trying something more natively C-Sharp-ish for Android... Eg.:

```
    WWW w = new WWW("https://my-amazon-function-to-call"); // tried pure old Http too
    yield return w;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(w.error)) {
        Debug.LogError(w.error);
    }
    else {
        var dict = Json.Deserialize(w.text) as Dictionary<string,object>;
        string oneTimeUploadUrl = (string)dict["oneTimeUploadUrl"];
        string resultUrl = (string)dict["resultUrl"];

    #if UNITY_IPHONE
        UnityWebRequest aws = UnityWebRequest.Put(oneTimeUploadUrl, bytes);
        yield return aws.Send();
        if(aws.isError) 
        {
            Debug.LogError("AWS ERROR: " + aws.error);
        }
        if(aws.responseCode == 200)
        {
            FeedShare(new Uri(resultUrl), _cachedMessage);    
        }
    #else             

    // Various Security Callback Tests
        //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (p1, p2, p3, p4) => true;
        //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);


        HttpWebRequest wreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(oneTimeUploadUrl);
        //wreq.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.None;
        //wreq.PreAuthenticate = false;
        wreq.Method = "PUT";
        wreq.ContentType = "image/png";
        wreq.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        Stream newStream = wreq.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        newStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wreq.GetResponse();
        if((int)response.StatusCode == 200)
        {
            FeedShare(new Uri(resultUrl), _cachedMessage);
        }
     #endif
    }
```

... but that also gives me a 403. I've tried a few different options, as you can see from the commented-out code, but no love. For the record, here are the SSL Policy functions that are used as the ServerCertificateValidationCallbacks:

```
public bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}

public bool MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback(System.Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
    bool isOk = true;
    if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None) {
        for (int i=0; i<chain.ChainStatus.Length; i++) {
            if (chain.ChainStatus [i].Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown) {
                chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;
                chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
                chain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan (0, 1, 0);
                chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllFlags;
                bool chainIsValid = chain.Build ((X509Certificate2)certificate);
                if (!chainIsValid) {
                    isOk = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print("MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback: " + isOk);
    return isOk;
}
```

This is the actual StackTrace:

```
04-01 11:14:57.325: I/Unity(22979):  
04-01 11:14:57.325: I/Unity(22979): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)
04-01 11:14:57.825: I/Unity(22979): WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
04-01 11:14:57.825: I/Unity(22979):   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
04-01 11:14:57.825: I/Unity(22979):   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
04-01 11:14:57.825: I/Unity(22979):  
04-01 11:14:57.825: I/Unity(22979): (Filename:  Line: -1)
```

At this point, I'm totally stuck... my only thought is to maybe write a native plugin... but would love to **NOT** have to do that...

Thoughts ???

Comment: Change your Minimum API level to 2.3.1.

Comment: Really ??? My current one is 4.2... I really don't want to support API 9... Do you have anything to back this up ?

Comment: I didn't know your target. If your target was 5.xx then that might be the problem. I solved a problem like that today by changing the API to 4.1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339575/how-to-access-texture-models-from-cloud-web-at-run-time-in-android-app-using-uni/36340219#36340219 Since you mentioned your API, that may not be the problem but it won't hurt to give it a try. Change to 4.1 not 2.3.1

Comment: Okay, will give it a try, also with 5.x

Comment: Let me know if that works

Comment: No, I actually was on 4.1, though for the sake or argument, I tried everything between 4.0.3 and 6.0 .. but no dice.

Comment: I have a possible solution before I spend time typing that, I want to ask you to do few more things. When you have `UnityWebRequest aws = UnityWebRequest.Put(oneTimeUploadUrl, bytes);` Can you put a simple `Text` display in your program and make it display value from `oneTimeUploadUrl` ? Run it on iOS then Android and compare the values. I just want to make sure that the `Deserialize` and `Dictionary` code are not failing on Android.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108002/discussion-between-jesses-co-tt-and-programmer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced kind of similar problem, where i was always getting 403. Then i found out that my server was checking for ***Content-Type*** and ***User-Agent*** in the **HEADER**. After i put them, its works. My code is:

```
UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest(url, UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPOST);
byte[] body = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(json_string);
www.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(body);
www.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
www.SetRequestHeader("User-Agent", "DefaultBrowser");
www.SetRequestHeader("Cookie", string.Format("DummyCookie"));
www.chunkedTransfer = false;
yield return www.Send();
```

Comment: My `UnityWebRequest` works when I specify browser name. For example: `request.SetRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0")`

Comment: for me it fixed the problem even without filling the user agent value with a normal name, it worked even with empty string ```""``` . thanks